# How do I reverse a list or loop over it backwards?

Tags: python, list

How do I iterate over a list in reverse in Python?

---

<sub>See also: [How can I get a reversed copy of a list (avoid a separate statement when chaining a method after .reverse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691/)</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: From what I can tell, the question was only ever intended to be about iteration. However, the day after it was asked, someone tried to fix the (rather poor) title - and misunderstood, giving it the title "How to reverse a list?" (which means changing around the order of the elements, **not** looking at the elements in a different order). The question then attracted answers for both problems, so now we have a rather confused canonical. I at least added to the title to indicate that both purposes are served here.

Answer (score 1671, accepted):

To get a *new* reversed list, apply the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function and collect the items into a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

```
>>> xs = [0, 10, 20, 40]
>>> list(reversed(xs))
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

To iterate backwards through a list:

```
>>> xs = [0, 10, 20, 40]
>>> for x in reversed(xs):
...     print(x)
40
20
10
0
```

Comment: can't you just use: array[::-1] ?

Comment: @kdlannoy According to the page linked to in the answer, "Compared to extended slicing, such as range(1,4)[::-1], reversed() is easier to read, runs faster, and uses substantially less memory. "

Comment: When I tested this slicing was about twice as fast (when reversing a 10k elements list and creating a list from it). I did not test memory consumption though. `reverse` might be faster though, if you don't need to cast to list afterwards.

Comment: worth noting that this is *not* the same as reverse([1,2,3]), n.b. the 'd' at the end ... which is one of the other answers below, which does this in-place, whereas this returns an iterator.

Comment: Why use `reversed()` instead of slicing? Read the Zen of Python, rule number 7: Readability counts!

Comment: The list versus iterator note at the bottom of this answer is really important to emphasize to python novices (like me!) as it caught me out badly when I used a reversed list in a loop and did not know about the single use only behaviour of an iterator (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data)

Comment: One more point with `reversed` you can't do like `l = [1,2,3]; b = l+reversed(l)` which cause `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "list_reverseiterator") to list`, but you can `b = l+l[::-1]`. Update: you can do it like: `b = l+list(reversed(l))`

Comment: In my opinion, `reversed()` is best for readability, `[::-1]` yields a list object (which is what we want - why yield a `list_reverseiterator` instead? you'd think most would want a reversed list here), and `.reverse()` only works in-place.

Answer (score 1521):

```
>>> xs = [0, 10, 20, 40]
>>> xs[::-1]
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

Extended slice syntax is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html). See also, [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what benefits (if any) does this have over list.reverse()?

Comment: It works for any interable, not just lists. Disadvantage is that it's not in place.

Comment: @Tim it returns a slice, so doesn't change the actual list contents

Comment: @Swiss Not in every iterable, for example, `set` is iterable, but not subscriptable.

Comment: @lunixbochs reversed returns an iterator and not a list in Python 3.

Comment: What's with the link to a super-old version of the Python doc?

Comment: @Swiss Python 2.3 allowed `list`, `tuple` and `str`  to utilize the extended slice syntax.

Comment: This works exactly for what OP wants, but it is very hacky, in a way that you have to use exactly `L[::-1]` and it won't take value for `start, stop` as `slice` method is defined with. Try with `L[4:0:-1]` and you will see problem.

Answer (score 461):

Use [`list.reverse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to reverse a list *in-place*:

```
>>> xs = [0, 10, 20, 40]
>>> xs.reverse()
>>> xs
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

Use slices to create a *new* list with the items in reverse order:

```
>>> xs[::-1]
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

Comment: [start:stop:step] so step is -1

Comment: Detail: The first modifies the list in-place, the second one just returns a new reversed list, but it doesn't modify the original one.

Comment: the second example should be `L=L[::-1]` to actually reverse the list otherwise you're only returning the values in reverse

Comment: let's say if i have l= [1,2,3,4,5,6] and n=2 them result must be [6,5,1,2,3,4], how can we do this

Comment: you could do this: `b = l[-n:]  b.reverse()  l = b + l[:len(l) - n]`

Comment: `List.reverse()` is better in case of additional memory limit ;)

Comment: Does list.reverse() use less memory?  I think it must make a copy of the data while reversing as you need to use a new variable name.  Compare the following   L=[1,2,3].reverse() and L=[1,2,3][::-1]    :-)

Comment: @AdrianTompkins: Umm... No. `list.reverse()` doesn't make a copy; `L=[1,2,3].reverse()` is equivalent to `L = None` but with some extra thumb twiddling before the final assignment. Like most mutating methods, it returns `None` (the implicit "Nothing to return here" marker) to make it clear it's operating in place.

Comment: Readability counts - use list.reverse()

Comment: I found  `pandas.cut(df, bins=lst.reverse())` did not work, while  `pandas.cut(df, bins=lst[::-1])` worked...

Answer (score 64):

### Summary of Reverse Methods

There are three different built-in ways to reverse a list. Which method is best depends on whether you need to:

1. Reverse an existing list in-place (altering the original list variable)

   - **Best solution is `object.reverse()` method**
2. Create an iterator of the reversed list (because you are going to feed it to a for-loop, a generator, etc.)

   - **Best solution is `reversed(object)` which creates the iterator**
3. Create a copy of the list, just in the reverse order (to preserve the original list)

   - **Best solution is using slices with a -1 step size: `object[::-1]`**

From a speed perspective, it is best to use the above built-in functions to reverse a list. For reversing, they are 2 to 8 times faster on short lists (10 items), and up to ~300+ times faster on long lists compared to a manually-created loop or generator. This makes sense -  they are written in a native language (i.e. C), have experts creating them, scrutiny, and optimization. They are also less prone to defects and more likely to handle edge and corner cases.

#### Test Script

Put all the code snippets in this answer together to make a script that will run the different ways of reversing a list that are described below. It will time each method while running it 100,000 times. The results are shown in the last section for lists of length 2, 10, and 1000 items.

```py
from timeit import timeit
from copy import copy

def time_str_ms(t):
    return '{0:8.2f} ms'.format(t * 1000)
```

### Method 1: Reverse in place with obj.reverse()

If the goal is just to reverse the order of the items in an existing list, without looping over them or getting a copy to work with, use the `<list>.reverse()` function. Run this directly on a list object, and the order of all items will be reversed:

Note that the following will reverse the original variable that is given, even though it also returns the reversed list back. i.e. you can create a copy by using this function output. Typically, you wouldn't make a function for this, but the timing script requires it.

We test the performance of this two ways - first just reversing a list in-place (changes the original list), and then copying the list and reversing it afterward to see if that is the fastest way to create a reversed copy compared to the other methods.

```py
def rev_in_place(mylist):
    mylist.reverse()
    return mylist

def rev_copy_reverse(mylist):
    a = copy(mylist)
    a.reverse()
    return a
```

### Method 2: Reverse a list using slices `obj[::-1]`

The built-in index slicing method allows you to make a copy of part of any indexed object.

- It does not affect the original object
- It builds a full list, not an iterator

The generic syntax is: `<object>[first_index:last_index:step]`. To exploit slicing to create a simple reversed list, use: `<list>[::-1]`. When leaving an option empty, it sets them to defaults of the first and last element of the object (reversed if the step size is negative).

Indexing allows one to use negative numbers, which count from the end of the object's index backwards (i.e. -2 is the second to last item). When the step size is negative, it will start with the last item and index backward by that amount.

```py
def rev_slice(mylist):
    a = mylist[::-1]
    return a
```

### Method 3: Reverse a list with the `reversed(obj)` iterator function

There is a `reversed(indexed_object)` function:

- This creates a reverse index iterator, not a list. Great if you are feeding it to a loop for better performance on large lists
- This creates a copy and does not affect the original object

Test with both a raw iterator, and creating a list from the iterator.

```py
def reversed_iterator(mylist):
    a = reversed(mylist)
    return a

def reversed_with_list(mylist):
    a = list(reversed(mylist))
    return a
```

### Method 4: Reverse list with Custom/Manual indexing

As the timing shows, creating your own methods of indexing is a bad idea. Use the built-in methods unless you really do need to do something custom. This simply means learning the built-in methods.

That said, there is not a huge penalty with smaller list sizes, but when you scale up the penalty becomes tremendous. The code below could be optimized, I'm sure, but it can't ever match the built-in methods as they are directly implemented in a native language.

```py
def rev_manual_pos_gen(mylist):
    max_index = len(mylist) - 1
    return [ mylist[max_index - index] for index in range(len(mylist)) ]

def rev_manual_neg_gen(mylist):
    ## index is 0 to 9, but we need -1 to -10
    return [ mylist[-index-1] for index in range(len(mylist)) ]

def rev_manual_index_loop(mylist):
    a = []
    reverse_index = len(mylist) - 1
    for index in range(len(mylist)):
        a.append(mylist[reverse_index - index])
    return a
    
def rev_manual_loop(mylist):
    a = []
    reverse_index = len(mylist)
    for index, _ in enumerate(mylist):
        reverse_index -= 1
        a.append(mylist[reverse_index])
    return a
```

### Timing each method

Following is the rest of the script to time each method of reversing. It shows reversing in place with `obj.reverse()` and creating the `reversed(obj)` iterator are always the fastest, while using slices is the fastest way to create a copy.

It also proves not to try to create a way of doing it on your own unless you have to!

```py
loops_to_test = 100000
number_of_items = 10
list_to_reverse = list(range(number_of_items))
if number_of_items < 15:
    print("a: {}".format(list_to_reverse))
print('Loops: {:,}'.format(loops_to_test))
# List of the functions we want to test with the timer, in print order
fcns = [rev_in_place, reversed_iterator, rev_slice, rev_copy_reverse,
        reversed_with_list, rev_manual_pos_gen, rev_manual_neg_gen,
        rev_manual_index_loop, rev_manual_loop]
max_name_string = max([ len(fcn.__name__) for fcn in fcns ])
for fcn in fcns:
    a = copy(list_to_reverse) # copy to start fresh each loop
    out_str = ' | out = {}'.format(fcn(a)) if number_of_items < 15 else ''
    # Time in ms for the given # of loops on this fcn
    time_str = time_str_ms(timeit(lambda: fcn(a), number=loops_to_test))
    # Get the output string for this function
    fcn_str = '{}(a):'.format(fcn.__name__)
    # Add the correct string length to accommodate the maximum fcn name
    format_str = '{{fx:{}s}} {{time}}{{rev}}'.format(max_name_string + 4)
    print(format_str.format(fx=fcn_str, time=time_str, rev=out_str))
```

### Timing Results

###### **NOTE: Below results run on Python 3.7.9**

The results show that scaling works best with the built-in methods best suited for a particular type of reversing. In other words, as the object element count increases, the built-in methods outpace the other methods by even more.

The built-in method that directly achieves what you need does better than stringing things together. i.e. slicing is best if you need a copy of the reversed list - it's faster than creating a duplicate list from `list(reversed(obj))` function, and faster than making a copy of the list and then doing an in-place `obj.reverse()`, but never by more than double the speed. Meanwhile - custom methods can take orders of magnitude longer with large lists.

For scaling, with a 1000 item list, the `reversed(<list>)` function call takes ~30 ms to setup the iterator, reversing in-place takes just ~55 ms, using the slice method takes ~210 ms to create a copy of the full reversed list, but the quickest manual method I made took **~8400 ms**.

With 2 items in the list:

```bash
a: [0, 1]
Loops: 100,000
rev_in_place(a):             24.70 ms | out = [1, 0]
reversed_iterator(a):        30.48 ms | out = <list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000020242580408>
rev_slice(a):                31.65 ms | out = [1, 0]
rev_copy_reverse(a):         63.42 ms | out = [1, 0]
reversed_with_list(a):       48.65 ms | out = [1, 0]
rev_manual_pos_gen(a):       98.94 ms | out = [1, 0]
rev_manual_neg_gen(a):       88.11 ms | out = [1, 0]
rev_manual_index_loop(a):    87.23 ms | out = [1, 0]
rev_manual_loop(a):          79.24 ms | out = [1, 0]
```

With 10 items in the list:

```bash
rev_in_place(a):             23.39 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
reversed_iterator(a):        30.23 ms | out = <list_reverseiterator object at 0x00000290A3CB0388>
rev_slice(a):                36.01 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
rev_copy_reverse(a):         64.67 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
reversed_with_list(a):       50.77 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
rev_manual_pos_gen(a):      162.83 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
rev_manual_neg_gen(a):      167.43 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
rev_manual_index_loop(a):   152.04 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
rev_manual_loop(a):         183.01 ms | out = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

And with 1000 items in the list:

```py
rev_in_place(a):             56.37 ms
reversed_iterator(a):        30.47 ms
rev_slice(a):               211.42 ms
rev_copy_reverse(a):        295.74 ms
reversed_with_list(a):      418.45 ms
rev_manual_pos_gen(a):     8410.01 ms
rev_manual_neg_gen(a):    11054.84 ms
rev_manual_index_loop(a): 10543.11 ms
rev_manual_loop(a):       15472.66 ms
```

#### Note: Dec, 2023 with Python 3.11 performance improvements

I ran a quick comparison of Python 3.7 to 3.11 (on the same PC just now) with 1 million cycles to see what difference the the 3.11 performance improvements would make. Python 3.11 was 26.5% faster on average, roughly the same for manual as for built in methods of reversing lists.

Answer (score 32):

For reversing the same list use:

```
array.reverse()
```

To assign reversed list into some other list use:

```
newArray = array[::-1]
```

Answer (score 31):

Using slicing, e.g. array = array[::-1], is a neat trick and very Pythonic, but a little obscure for newbies maybe. Using the reverse() method is a good way to go in day to day coding because it is easily readable.

However, if you need to reverse a list in place as in an interview question, you will likely not be able to use built in methods like these.  The interviewer will be looking at how you approach the problem rather than the depth of Python knowledge, an algorithmic approach is required. The following example, using a classic swap, might be one way to do it:-

```
def reverse_in_place(lst):      # Declare a function
    size = len(lst)             # Get the length of the sequence
    hiindex = size - 1
    its = size/2                # Number of iterations required
    for i in xrange(0, its):    # i is the low index pointer
        temp = lst[hiindex]     # Perform a classic swap
        lst[hiindex] = lst[i]
        lst[i] = temp
        hiindex -= 1            # Decrement the high index pointer
    print "Done!"

# Now test it!!
array = [2, 5, 8, 9, 12, 19, 25, 27, 32, 60, 65, 1, 7, 24, 124, 654]

print array                    # Print the original sequence
reverse_in_place(array)        # Call the function passing the list
print array                    # Print reversed list


**The result:**
[2, 5, 8, 9, 12, 19, 25, 27, 32, 60, 65, 1, 7, 24, 124, 654]
Done!
[654, 124, 24, 7, 1, 65, 60, 32, 27, 25, 19, 12, 9, 8, 5, 2]
```

Note that this will not work on Tuples or string sequences, because strings and tuples are immutable, i.e., you cannot write into them to change elements.

Comment: The classic swap could be done via `lst[hiindex], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[hiindex]`, I think... ;-)

Comment: @Samoth That syntax isn't as clear and the behavior isn't exactly obvious. Distinct steps make more sense.

Comment: why people say that things like array[::-1] are pythonic? The python zen teach us that explicit is better than implicit and readability counts. Stuff like that are not explicit and readable at all.

Comment: @k4ppa: `array[::-1]` is perfectly readable and perfectly explicit *if you know Python*. "Readable" doesn't mean "someone who has never used Python slicing before must be able to read it"; the `[::-1]` reversing slice is a ridiculously common idiom in Python (you'll encounter it in existing code all the time), and it's perfectly readable *if you regularly use Python*. Sure, `first10 = []`, `for i in range(10): first10.append(array[i])` is clear and explicit, but that doesn't make it better than `first10 = array[:10]`.

Comment: Why is the number of iterations size/2? What's the logic behind it? Also, what if it's length isn't an even number. Then would it be ceil(size/2)

Comment: It has to be size/2 because you are working both ends of the list at the same iteration, if you used just length, you would reverse the list again back to the start point.  For odd list lengths, the mid point does not have to swap 

Comment: This is one of my favourite coding challenge questions to give to a candidate, and it does not have to be python it would work equally well with Perl, bash, C#, PHP etc. There are several avenues you could pursue like is a list as a parameter passed by value or reference, do you really need to return the result if passed by reference, what would happen if you were passing a string, would it still work?  Etc,

Answer (score 22):

I find (contrary to some other suggestions) that `l.reverse()` is by far the fastest way to reverse a long list in Python 3 and 2. I'd be interested to know if others can replicate these timings.

`l[::-1]` is probably slower because it copies the list prior to reversing it. Adding the `list()` call around the iterator made by `reversed(l)` must add some overhead. Of course if you want a copy of the list or an iterator then use those respective methods, but if you want to just reverse the list then `l.reverse()` seems to be the fastest way.

Functions

```
def rev_list1(l):
    return l[::-1]

def rev_list2(l):
    return list(reversed(l))

def rev_list3(l):
    l.reverse()
    return l
```

List

```
l = list(range(1000000))
```

Python 3.5 timings

```
timeit(lambda: rev_list1(l), number=1000)
# 6.48
timeit(lambda: rev_list2(l), number=1000)
# 7.13
timeit(lambda: rev_list3(l), number=1000)
# 0.44
```

Python 2.7 timings

```
timeit(lambda: rev_list1(l), number=1000)
# 6.76
timeit(lambda: rev_list2(l), number=1000)
# 9.18
timeit(lambda: rev_list3(l), number=1000)
# 0.46
```

Comment: `list.reverse` is the fastest, because it reverses in place

Comment: You're correct `list.reverse()` is fastest, but you're penalizing `reversed` (which is best used when you *don't* want a new `list`, just to iterate an existing `list` in reverse order without mutating the original), and the slice (which also avoids mutating the original `list`, and is typically faster than `reversed` when the input is small). Yes, if you don't need the copy, anything that copies is more expensive, but a lot of the time, you don't want to mutate the original value.

Comment: It looks like `reversed` [still loses to `list.reverse()`](https://tio.run/##rZHPasMwDMbvfgrdYkMWmqanlDzJGCFrlM3gP6nslJaxZ8@ULC3NBjuM6mCMvp8@SXZ/ie/eFWNH3kLUFnUEbXtPEQh7bOLYYsfXU210iLk0qhTAQRgHcmCey/IpfxHintr@ojgpWUUK2LKo1nxx4022UFKt6tf87qf/nbUQBqqlYePeUOabKbhlYLZnLZlXPXhj8BC1d@G6b4vHAfesuDBYZHJOSNucDbpqozI8R3TtHmaDuraNdnV9rTbpbb6PT2gCUCJET9pFabWT348pk8Vd0vQMSQrzVNV8Zp0ny0yuUnCDfUWqpuHT5SOqQvEW/3LcPtyxeLjj7g/HcfwC "Python 3 – Try It Online") even so, but given it doesn't mutate the input `list`, it's better in many cases. The loss for `reversed` is small (~1/6th longer than `list.reverse()`).

Answer (score 18):

```
for x in array[::-1]:
    do stuff
```

Comment: This slicing method is not very readable. The Pythonic way would be to use the reverse() method. ;-)

Comment: @SimonM reverse() is definitely easier to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 17):

With [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) and [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> reversed_list = list(reversed(list1))
>>> reversed_list
>>> [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
array=[0,10,20,40]
for e in reversed(array):
  print e
```

Answer (score 8):

Using reversed(array) would be the likely best route.

```
>>> array = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for item in reversed(array):
>>>     print item
```

Should you need to understand how could implement this without using the built in `reversed`.

```
def reverse(a):
    midpoint = len(a)/2
    for item in a[:midpoint]:
        otherside = (len(a) - a.index(item)) - 1
        temp = a[otherside]
        a[otherside] = a[a.index(item)]
        a[a.index(item)] = temp
    return a
```

This should take O(N) time.

Comment: Was looking for how to do that without using the reverse function. Thanks.

Comment: Or to reverse in place use list = list.reverse()

Comment: Is a list, a, passed in by value or by reference?  It is passed by reverence, so you do not need return a. You have modified at the original memory location of a

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to use [numpy.flip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) for this

```
import numpy as np
array = [0, 10, 20, 40]
list(np.flip(array))
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

Comment: Great, very memorable. And unlike others solutions (shame on the OP for such a non-generic test case) it works even for unsorted lists (random numbers, etc).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store the elements of reversed list in some other variable, then you can use `revArray = array[::-1]` or `revArray = list(reversed(array))`.

But the first variant is slightly faster:

```
z = range(1000000)
startTimeTic = time.time()
y = z[::-1]
print("Time: %s s" % (time.time() - startTimeTic))

f = range(1000000)
startTimeTic = time.time()
g = list(reversed(f))
print("Time: %s s" % (time.time() - startTimeTic))
```

Output:

```
Time: 0.00489711761475 s
Time: 0.00609302520752 s
```

Comment: Next time, you might want to use `timeit`.

Comment: This is a bad test for two reasons. Firstly, the fact that you only test one iteration - of something that only takes a few milliseconds to execute - means the result may be a fluke. Secondly, depending upon whether you used Python 2 or Python 3, `range(1000000)` may not be a list at all, but rather a `range` object, with its own `__reversed__` method that presumably behaves differently from that of a `list`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [bitwise complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278779/bit-wise-operation-unary-invert) of the array index to step through the array in reverse:

```
>>> array = [0, 10, 20, 40]
>>> [array[~i] for i, _ in enumerate(array)]
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

Whatever you do, *don't* do it this way ;)

Answer (score 4):

### Using some logic

Using some old school logic to practice for interviews.

> Swapping numbers front to back. Using two pointers `index[0] and index[last]`

```
def reverse(array):
    n = array
    first = 0
    last = len(array) - 1
    while first < last:
      holder = n[first]
      n[first] = n[last]
      n[last] = holder
      first += 1
      last -= 1
    return n

input -> [-1 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
output -> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -1]
```

Comment: If we divide the list in two and swap the first with the last index and the time complexity will be more efficient than the sample listed.

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehension:

```
[array[n] for n in range(len(array)-1, -1, -1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

**ORGANIZING VALUES**:

In Python, lists' order too can be manipulated with sort, organizing your variables in numerical/alphabetical order:
Temporarily:

print(sorted(my_list))

Permanent:

```
my_list.sort(), print(my_list)
```

You can sort with the flag "reverse=True":

```
print(sorted(my_list, reverse=True))

or

my_list.sort(reverse=True), print(my_list)
```

**WITHOUT ORGANIZING**

Maybe you do not want to sort values, but only reverse the values. Then we can do it like this:

```
print(list(reversed(my_list)))
```

**Numbers have priority over alphabet in listing order. The Python values' organization is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not how to return a list in reverse but rather how to reverse a list with an example list name `array`.

To reverse a list named `"array"` use `array.reverse()`.

The incredibly useful slice method as described can also be used to reverse a list in place by defining the list as a sliced modification of itself using `array[:] = array[::-1]`.

Comment: The last sentence is not true, this does not reverse a list in place; it should say `array[:] = array[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

With minimum amount of built-in functions, assuming it's interview settings

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7, 8]
inverse = [] #create container for inverse array
length = len(array)  #to iterate later, returns 8 
counter = length - 1  #because the 8th element is on position 7 (as python starts from 0)

for i in range(length): 
   inverse.append(array[counter])
   counter -= 1
print(inverse)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 methods to get the reversed list:

1. Slicing Method 1:    `reversed_array = array[-1::-1]`
2. Slicing Method 2:
   `reversed_array2 = array[::-1]`
3. Using the builtin function: `reversed_array = array.reverse()`

The third function actually reversed the list object in place. That means no copy of pristine data is maintained. This is a good approach if you don't want to maintain the old version. But doesn't seem to be a solution if you do want the pristine and reversed version.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct translation of your requirement into Python is this `for` statement:

```
for i in xrange(len(array) - 1, -1, -1):
   print i, array[i]
```

This is rather cryptic but may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(my_list):
  L = len(my_list)
  for i in range(L/2):
    my_list[i], my_list[L-i - 1] = my_list[L-i-1], my_list[i]
  return my_list
```

Comment: Better with `//` floor division operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(text):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(text)-1, -1, -1):
        output.append(text[i])
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always treat the list like a stack just popping the elements off the top of the stack from the back end of the list. That way you take advantage of first in last out characteristics of a stack. Of course you are consuming the 1st array. I do like this method in that it's pretty intuitive in that you see one list being consumed from the back end while the other is being built from the front end.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; nl=[]
>>> while l:
        nl.append(l.pop())  
>>> print nl
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_data = [1,2,3,4,5]
l = len(list_data)
i=l+1
rev_data = []
while l>0:
  j=i-l
  l-=1
  rev_data.append(list_data[-j])
print "After Rev:- %s" %rev_data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L = [L[-i] for i in range(1, len(L) + 1)]
>>> L
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print(reduce(lambda acc, x: [x] + acc, l, []))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This solution is about 4.5k times slower than `l[::-1]`, and at the same time much less legible. Functional programming in Python is sadly rather slow.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing in-place by switching references of opposite indices:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]    
>>> for i in range(len(l)//2):
...     l[i], l[-1-i] = l[-1-i], l[i]
...
>>> l
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Works for odd length lists!

Comment: My solution is right! You know how python implements indexing. From right to left you have 0,1,2... and from left to right you have -1,-2,-3.. etc. To reverse a list, you cut it into two parts and you multiply the indexes on the right by their opposites on the left minus one.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using `__reverse__` , which returns a generator.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in l.__reversed__():
...   print i
... 
5
4
3
2
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
print(list(reversed(list_name)))
```

Comment: `<list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000021C517D3DA0>`

Comment: This output is unreadable... Use `print(list(reversed(list_name)))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Reverse of a user input values in one line code:**

```
for i in input()[::-1]: print(i,end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This class uses Python magic methods and iterators for reversing, and reverses a list:

```
class Reverse(object):
    """ Builds a reverse method using magic methods """

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)


    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration

        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]


REV_INSTANCE = Reverse([0, 10, 20, 40])

iter(REV_INSTANCE)

rev_list = []
for i in REV_INSTANCE:
    rev_list.append(i)

print(rev_list)
```

#### Output

```
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to lazily evaluate the reverse using a **generator**:

```
def reverse(seq):
    for x in range(len(seq), -1, -1): #Iterate through a sequence starting from -1 and increasing by -1.
        yield seq[x] #Yield a value to the generator
```

Now iterate through like this:

```
for x in reverse([1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
```

If you need a list:

```
l = list(reverse([1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative way using list comprehension and abs

```
array = [0, 10, 20, 40]

reversed_array = [array[abs(indx)] for indx in range(abs(len(array)-1),1)]
            
reversed_array
[40, 20, 10, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The cute Solution


class List_reverse():
    def reverse_list(self):
        list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        list1 = []
        for i in range(1, len(list)+1):
            list1.append(list[-i])
        print(list1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = List_reverse()
    obj.reverse_list()
    enter code here
```

Comment: What makes this "cute", and how is it better than the 50 or so existing answers? Please read [answer], and please make sure to explain the code you share.

Answer (score -1):

A clean simple class object to solve your issue.

```
class lister():
    def reverse(self):
        return  [self[len(self)-e]for e,x in enumerate(self,start=1)]
print(lister.reverse([0, 10, 20, 40]))
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this question come up during a python code test for a job interview.
The below is my answer.
Note it works for any value any length

```
def get_reverse(list_check, count_num):
    final_list =[]
    for index in range(list_length):
        value = list_check[count_num]
        final_list.append(value)
        count_num = count_num -1

    return final_list

new_list = ['A', 'GOAT', 'C', 'D', 'Mac']

list_length = len(new_list)
x = list_length -1

print(get_reverse(new_list, x))
```

Comment: There there are several points that make your function more complicated and un-pythonic than necessary – but there's a fatal error: `list_length`, which is used inside the function, exists only as a global variable. That's why I'll downvote this answer (but I'll retract the DV if you fix that).