# Python : Reverse Order Of List

Tags: python, string, list, class, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reverse a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

How do I reverse the order of a list:
eg. I have `lines.sort(key = itemgetter(2))`

that is a sorted list. What if I wanted that list exactly as it is ordered, but in reverse order?

Comment: When marking something as a duplicate, it's useful to give a link to what it's a duplicate of.  Here's a link for this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
lines.sort(key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

or if you just want to reverse the list

```
lines.reverse()
```

or if you want to copy the list into a new, reversed list

```
reversed(lines)
```

Comment: The last example returns an iterable, not a list. You'd have to use `list(reversed(lines))` for that to become a list again. It's easier to use a negative stride slice instead: `lines[::-1]`.

Comment: And the nice thing about negative strides is that it works for other types as well:  `tuple`, `str` ...

Answer (score 22):

Do you want sort the list (in place) such that the greatest elements are first and the smallest elements are last (greatest and "smallest" determined by your `key` or `cmp` function)?  If so, use the other answers.  (If you want to sort out of place, use `sorted` instead).

A simple way to reverse the order (out of place) of *any list* is via slicing:

```
reverse_lst = lst[::-1]
```

Note that this works with other [sequence objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) as well (`tuple` and `str` come to mind immediately)

Comment: I think that the statement "reversing the list while sorting it" is somehow unclear.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky -- I've edited.  Is this any better?

Comment: I think it would be better to say it works for _any sequence_ because `list` is a concrete data type in Python.

Comment: @martineau -- added a link to the documentation on sequence objects.