# Django Template Won't Display List

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I've had a look at previous questions, and I'm unable to find an answer to my issue.
I'm trying to display a 2D list, which I have done earlier in the HTML with a different list.
I've used a similar method for the other list but it wont display, I'm just getting the headers.

HTML:

```
    <table class="listtable" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Account No</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for person in user %}
    <tr>
        {% for message in person %}
        <td>{% autoescape off %}{{ message }}{% endautoescape %}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I've printed the list in the view, so I know that within the view it is correct. I am 100% sure that I've used the correct variables as well.
The code in the view is similar to:

```
user = get_data_from_other_source()
for item in user:
    print(item)
```

The print displays exactly what it should.
The list is along the lines off:

```
[4, '<account number>', '<time>', 'somestring']
[3, '<account number>', '<time>', 'somestring']
```

The page source says:

```
<table class="listtable" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Account No</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Messages</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

**EDIT**: Moderated view code..

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def page_control(request):
    acc_no = request.session['acc_no']

    user = setup_page_control (acc_no)
    for item in user:
        print(item)
    return render_to_response("<htmlfile>.html",
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))



def setup_user_control(acc_no):
    messages = <outside magic>
    user = reversed(messages)
    return user
```

I have gutted a lot out of the code, and changed variable names etc..
I've only deleted stuff which I am 100% sure are not the problem

Comment: use a different context variable name. Change `user` to `user_list` or something.

Comment: Paste the whole view code if you can.

Comment: I have changed variable names, "user" is something else, i've had to change things for security

Comment: I'd like to add that I am NOT using the built-in database for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explanation for the issue you found:

[`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) returns a reverse [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator). This is **NOT** the reversed list as you expect it to be:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print reversed(a)
<listreverseiterator object at 0x...>
```

As you can see, reversed(a) is not the list in reverse, but the actual iterator itself. In order to get the reversed list like you want you can use:

```
user = list(reversed(messages))
# or
user = messages[::-1]
```

(source: [How can I reverse a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python))

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for clearing it up for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your response should be like this:

```
 return render_to_response("<htmlfile>.html",
                          {'user':user},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This was not my problem, I've added my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've found my issue, but I'm not sure why it happened.
When I removed:

```
user = reversed(messages)
```

The template was willing to output the list again. Awfully odd. If anyone knows why, it would be great for an explanation :)

Comment: What does the debug for messages output?

Comment: There was no error, it was even printing correctly, it just wouldn't output to the template