# Reverse list of strings python [One Liner]

Tags: python, reverse

I am trying to reverse a list of strings. For instance

> one two three

will be output as

> three two one

I have tried this

```
[x for x in range(input()) [" ".join(((raw_input().split())[::-1]))]]
```

but I am getting an error:

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse a list in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Comment: do you want the result in a string or a list

Comment: I need to achieve this in single line and need the output as a string. I know to reverse a string. The issue is when I try to create a single line code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually address your code and why it fails with an error,  you are trying to index the range list with a `str` i.e  `" ".join((raw_input().split()[::-1]))`:

```
range(input())[" ".join((raw_input().split()[::-1]))]
```

You would need to loop over the inner list for your code to run without error:

```
 [s for x in range(input()) for s in [" ".join((raw_input().split()[::-1]))]]
```

Which would output something like:

```
2
foo bar
foob barb
['bar foo', 'barb foob']
```

And can simplify to:

```
[" ".join((raw_input().split()[::-1])) for _ in range(input())]
```

If you want a single string just call join on the outer list, I would also recommend using `int(raw_input(...` generally but I know you are code golfing.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> ' '.join("one two three".split()[::-1])
'three two one'
```

you can use like this,

```
>>> ' '.join(raw_input().split()[::-1])
one two three
'three two one'
```

Comment: Might help to actually explain why the OP's code did not work

Comment: This is already in the code, it throws type error when I create a single line code. I am trying codegolf to be frank

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> t="one two three"
>>> " ".join( reversed(t.split()) )
'three two one'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `raw_input()` try this:

```
>>> " ".join((raw_input().split())[::-1])
one two three
'three two one'
```