# Functions with strings

Tags: python, string, function

I am working pyhton on codecademy and I stucked in one part. The goal is this: "Define a function called reverse that takes a string 'text' and returns that string in reverse. You may not use reversed or [::-1] to help you with this."
I did this one and it is not working like this:

```
t = raw_input("Enter: ")
def reverse(t):
    x = []
    for a in range(len(t)):
       x.append(t[len(t) - a - 1])
    print ''.join(x)
```

but when I do it like this it is working.

```
t = raw_input("Enter: ")
x = []
for a in range(len(t)):
   x.append(t[len(t) - a - 1])
print ''.join(x)
```

what is wrong with the first one?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Some users are unable to follow links to images, so if you want your question to be answered, please copy and paste your code into your question. Thank you.

Comment: Please paste your code into your question. Don't use pictures for code.

Comment: The images are the same. Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse a list in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Is it homework? Please notice that Python in NOT C/C++ language. To reverse a text consider: `"text"[::-1]` => `"txet"`.

Comment: In the first one?  Are you calling reverse (and if so, are you getting a response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first does not work because, you're not calling your `reverse` function on `t`.

```
def reverse(t):
    x = []
    for a in range(len(t)):
        x.append(t[len(t)-a-1])
    return ''.join(x)

t = raw_input("Enter: ")
print(reverse(t))
```

In your example you're obtaining the input, but doing nothing with it.