# How to replace multiple substrings in a list?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, replace

I need to turn the input_string into the comment below using a for loop. First I sliced it using the `split()` function, but now I need to somehow turn the input string into `['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result5']`. I tried replacing the `.xls` and the dash for nothing (`''`), but the string output is unchanged.  Please don't import anything, I'm trying to do this with functions and loops only.

```
input_string = "01-result.xls,2-result.xls,03-result.xls,05-result.xls" 
# Must be turned into ['result1','result2', 'result3', 'result5']

splitted = input_string.split(',')

for c in ['.xls', '-', '0']:
    if c in splitted:
        splitted = splitted.replace(splitted, 'c', '')
```

When I type `splitted`, the output is `['01-result.xls', '2-result.xls', '03-result.xls', '05-result.xls']` therefore nothing is happening.

Comment: I also need this for a general case, not specifically for this case.

Comment: you can use regular expressions

Comment: @BenjaGarrido Yes, They are the easiest to understand but unfortunately they are slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [re module's `sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) function and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
>>> input_string = "01-result.xls,2-result.xls,03-result.xls,05-result.xls" 
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\w+)\.xls',r'\2\1',input_string)
'result01,result2,result03,result05'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\w+)\.xls',r'\2\1',input_string).split(',')
['result01', 'result2', 'result03', 'result05']
```

Using no imports, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> [''.join(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[::-1]) for x in input_string.split(',')]
['result01', 'result2', 'result03', 'result05']
```

The algo here is, we loop through the string after splitting it on `,`. Now we split the individual words on `.` and the first element of these on `-`. We now have the number and the words, which we can easily [`join`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

---

Complete explanation of the list comp answer -

To understand what a list comprehension is, Read [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/4099593)

Coming to the answer,

Splitting the input list on `,`, gives us the list of individual file names

```
>>> input_string.split(',')
['01-result.xls', '2-result.xls', '03-result.xls', '05-result.xls']
```

Now using the list comprehension construct, we can iterate through this,

```
>>> [i for i in input_string.split(',')]
['01-result.xls', '2-result.xls', '03-result.xls', '05-result.xls']
```

As we need only the file name and not the extension, we `split` by using `.` and take the first value.

```
>>> [i.split('.')[0] for i in input_string.split(',')]
['01-result', '2-result', '03-result', '05-result']
```

Now again, what we need is the number and the name as two parts. So we again split by `-`

```
>>> [i.split('.')[0].split('-') for i in input_string.split(',')]
[['01', 'result'], ['2', 'result'], ['03', 'result'], ['05', 'result']]
```

Now we have the [number, name] in a list, However the format that we need is `"namenumber"`. Hence we have two options

- Concat them like `i.split('.')[0].split('-')[1]+i.split('.')[0].split('-')[0]`. This is an unnecessarily long way
- Reverse them and join. We can use slices to reverse a list (See [How can I reverse a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)) and `str.join` to join like `''.join(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[::-1])`.

So we get our final list comprehension

```
>>> [''.join(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[::-1]) for x in input_string.split(',')]
['result01', 'result2', 'result03', 'result05']
```

Comment: haha I didn't see your list comprehension before I submitted my answer. +1 for the two solutions.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks, I would not have edited if I saw your answer. :)

Comment: can someone explain exactly what is happening in Rao's list comprehension answer. he's joining then splitting at '-' and '.' ?

Comment: @mariano Done, Please take a look and inform me if you still have any queries

Comment: Why couldn't I have used the reverse function instead?

Comment: @mariano In this case you can use both. Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using list comprehension and string manipulation if you don't want to use re.

```
input_string = "01-result.xls,2-result.xls,03-result.xls,05-result.xls"
 # Must be turned into ['result1','result2', 'result3', 'result5']

splitted = input_string.split(',')

#Remove extension, then split by hyphen, switch the two values,
#and combine them into the result string
print ["".join(i.split(".")[0].split("-")[::-1]) for i in splitted]

#Output
#['result01', 'result2', 'result03', 'result05']
```

The way this list comprehension works is:

1. Take the list of results and remove the ".xls". `i.split(".)[0]`
2. Split on the `-` and switch positions of the number and "result". `.split("-")[::-1]`
3. For every item in the list, join the list into a string. `"".join()`

Comment: Pro-tip, Always explain outside the code blocks. The CSS for comments is too faded to meet the eye.