# lambda python function in reversing list

Tags: python

```
scores = []
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split(',')
        score = int(score)
        scores.append((name, score))
        scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])
for name, score in scores:
    print(name + ", " + str(score))
```

This code can be used to show a txt file looking like this (disordered):

```
alpha, 3
beta, 1
gamma, 2
```

To looking like this:

```
beta, 1
gamma, 2
alpha, 3
```

How can I modify the code so that it instead prints as:

```
alpha, 3
gamma, 2
beta, 1
```

Comment: `scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`reverse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) argument to `list.sort()`:

```
scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[1], reverse=True)
```

From the documentation:

> *reverse* is a boolean value. If set to `True`, then the list elements are
>   sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `scores[::-1]` instead of `scores` in the last for-loop. Here's a small illustration of this behaviour:

```
a=list(range(10))
print(a[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reverse` when you sort:

```
>>> l  = [('a', 1), ('c',5), ('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
>>> l
[('c', 5), ('a', 2), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)]
```

You can use it with `sorted`:

```
>>> l  = [('a', 1), ('c',5), ('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
[('c', 5), ('a', 2), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)]
>>>
```