# Python List Comprehension Reverseal

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, factors

So I wrote a Python statement takes a variable named n and creates a list of n's factors smallest to largest.  I would I rewrite this statement to reverse the list to output it as largest to smallest?

Here is the statement:

```
factors = [x for x in range(2,n) if n % x == 0]
```

Comment: Yes. Yes you would like to rewrite this statement to reverse the list to output it as largest to smallest

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python).

Comment: Replace your range with `range(n-1, 1, -1)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use reverse.

```
>>> test = [1,2,3,4]
>>> test.reverse()
>>> test
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```