# String reversing of many strings

Tags: python-3.x

Input should be "one two three" and output should be "three two one".

I tried this but didn't work

```
s="One Two Three"

ori=s.split(" ")

print(ori)

rev=ori.reverse()

print(rev)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse a list in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python slice, so the answer to this question is:

```
>>> rev = ori[::-1]
>>> print(rev)
['Three', 'Two', 'One']
```

You can learn more about slices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/4671441)