# Cumulative sum starting from the right

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe which in general form looks like this.

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  6
2  3  5  7
```

I'd like to create another dataframe where in each value is the cumulative sum along the row of values in the original dataframe, *starting from the right, rather than the left* - i.e. the output should look like this:

```
   A  B  C
0  6  5  3
1  12 10 6
2  ...
```

Can anyone suggest a bit of code to do this?

Comment: doesn't the prospect of you writing some clumsy code before asking sound exciting? This is an interesting task after all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for [reversing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3940137/2901002) values twice:

```
df = df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1]
print (df)
    A   B  C
0   6   5  3
1  12  10  6
2  15  12  7
```

---

```
#first reverse values
print (df.iloc[:, ::-1])
   C  B  A
0  3  2  1
1  6  4  2
2  7  5  3

#then use function cumsum
print (df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1))
   C   B   A
0  3   5   6
1  6  10  12
2  7  12  15

#last reverse back 
print (df.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1])

    A   B  C
0   6   5  3
1  12  10  6
2  15  12  7
```