# Reverse accessing a list in python

Tags: python, list

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
for a[-1] in a :
    print a[-1]
```

This Program gives me an output
0
1
2
2

I am not able to decode it. I was expecting it to print the list in reverse direction. or at least print 3 alone. Can someone help me to understand this output

Comment: reusing `a` to assign it back to itself isn't a good idea. use `for i in reversed(a): print i`

Comment: I think what you were _trying_ to write ia `for x in a[::-1]:`? If you're going to copy random code from unspecified places, you have to understand what it means, or at least copy it exactly.

Comment: By writing `for a[-1] in a`, making `a[-1]` the loop variable, you're assigning each value in the array, in turn, to the last slot in the array. Hopefully it's clear why that's a bad idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python

Comment: I don't understand the code properly. Got it from internet. I was curious to know the output.  I know how to reverse a string in python. I was seeking for a help in understanding the output for this specific question. What is actually happening in the list is what i wanted to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at each iteration `a[-1]` (the last element of `a`) is assigned a value of `a` (the list becomes `[0,1,2,0]` then `[0,1,2,1]` then `[0,1,2,2]`)

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
for a[-1] in a :
    print(a[-1])
```

It "works" until the end (although forward, not reversed), where the last iteration yields the last iterated upon value: `2`

Now of course if you just want to iterate a list backwards:

```
for i in reversed(a):
   print(i)
```

`reversed(a)` is better than `a[::-1]` here because it doesn't create a list just to iterate on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
for x in a[::-1]:
    print x
```

Which goes "reads" the list in reverse order, one element at a time. A `list` is implicitly "read" like `a[::1]`. If you'd like to "read" a `list` in reverse order but every second element you could use `a[::-2]` which would give you `[3, 1]`.

Or you can use

```
for x in reversed(a):
    print x
```