# Generating and slicing a reversed list

Tags: python, list, reverse

This is probably silly and basic but how do I get the list `edcba`

When I try:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
letters[4:0:-1]
```

'edcb'

This somehow makes sense since the index is [4,3,2,1]. However, using `-1` results in the following:

```
letters[4:-1:-1]
```

''

I know I could just do `"".join(reversed(letters[:5]))` or use list comprehension but I am curious on how to do it with negative steps.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem to be honest...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Sorry! what's an X-Y problem? and I was the reason it is not a duplicate is because the other question is only about reversing the list, I am trying to reverse and slice at the same time. I was using two concepts that individually work but together gave me a somewhat unexpected result.

Comment: You might wish to [read this for more info on the "X-Y Problem"](http://xyproblem.info/).  Here's the [related FAQ directly from meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`letters[4::-1]`, which is basically `letters[4:None:-1]`

Think of the `slice` this way:

```
[element to start at: 
 element to start excluding: 
 steps]
```

So by not explicitly stating `0` in the second part of the slice, you're telling the interpreter to start from index `4` and go step `-1` until no elements are found.

Another way to visualize this is if you were to do this forward and want `"vwxyz"`, you wouldn't use `letters[21:25:1]`, but just `letters[21:]` which translates to `letters[21:None:1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
lent = len(letters)
data = []
for l in range(1,lent):
    total = lent - int(l)
    data.append(letters[total])
data.append(letters[0])
print(data)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21586061)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
letters[4:-1:-1]
```

The reason why you unexpectedly get an empty string as the result is that you've asked to go from index `4`, until reaching the end of the string (`-1`), by steps of `-1`.

The index `-1` in this context is equivalent to the index `25`, so you've essentially done `letters[4:25:-1]` -- as soon as python tries to evaluate the first item in the slice it's done because you've already stepped beyond the bounds. The same sort of expression with a positive increment would be `letters[5:4]` -- it's done before it starts.