# How do I list numbers from greatest to lowest?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment to take a number and to sort it in a ascending and descending order and then add it together to get a result. I know how to get the number sorted in a ascending order but not descending. For my code I have:

```
def addition(num):
    listedDes = list(str(num))
    listedDes.sort()
    print("".join(listedDes))
addition(3524)
```

Comment: Descending: `listedDes.sort(reverse=True)`.

Comment: You know how to sort - the problem reduces down to  [How can I reverse a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python) .. this is more awkward then `.sort(reverse=True)` or `.sort(key=lambda x:-x)` but would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by Descending by doing like this.

```
listedDes.sort(reverse=True)
```

Here's more in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#ascending-and-descending

Comment: No but it worked! Thank You. I just figured out that I can to listedDes.sort(reverse=True) and it also works. But still TY!

Comment: Yeah. It works. But it was also a typo. I wrote answer to fast. Now corrected. Cheers.

Comment: Ty dude you are really the best ^^.

Answer (score 0):

```
def addition(num):
    listedDes = list(str(num))
    listedDes.sort()
    listedDes.reverse()
    print("".join(listedDes))
addition(3524)
```

This is already known answer but here I am writing for your understanding.