# How to reverseTuples defined in list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I don't know how to explain this but I will try. I have pre-defined tuples and a list which contains those tuples:

```
EL = (42.7358, -84.4844)
Det = (42.3831, -83.1022)
Kal = (42.2747, -85.5883)
AA = (42.2753, -83.7308)
Lan = (42.7092, -84.5539)
GR = (42.9614, -85.6558)
SSM = (46.4844, -84.3656)

cities = [EL, Det, Kal, AA, Lan, GR, SSM]
```

1. The cities is in (x, y) order. How can I swap the order to (y, x) and saving it as cities2.
2. How can I reverse the order of the elements in cities? For example, it will be like this:

   ```
   cities3 = [SSM, GR, Lan, AA, Kal, Det, EL]
   ```

I've tried cities.reverse(), but it reversed the coordinate. Any hints and helps would be much appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about reversing the items:

```
cities.reverse()
```

`reverse` does the job, reversing in place the items (it modifies `cities`):

Since you have tuples of coordinates, it is not possible to swap in place `(x,y)` but
,if you want to create another list, list comprehensions is one of the right tools to use.

If you want swap `(x,y)` to `(x,y)`:

```
cities_swap_xy = [(y,x) for (x,y) in cities]
```

to create another list with reversed order:

```
cities_reverse = cities[-1:0:-1]
```

to swap coordinates and reverse city:

```
cities_reverse_and_swap_xy = [(y,x) for (x,y) in cities[-1:0:-1]]
```

There is a lot of documentation about list comprehensions, good learning!

Comment: Hi!  Many thanks for the tips! It helped me a lot and gave me some ideas how to manipulate the elements. Now I know the keyword is "list comprehension".

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of tuples. Swapping tuples is simply a matter of accessing the 1st index in the tuple before 0 index and storing the output.

```
EL = (42.7358, -84.4844)
Det = (42.3831, -83.1022)
Kal = (42.2747, -85.5883)
AA = (42.2753, -83.7308)
Lan = (42.7092, -84.5539)
GR = (42.9614, -85.6558)
SSM = (46.4844, -84.3656)

cities = [EL, Det, Kal, AA, Lan, GR, SSM]
print(cities)
#Output:
[(42.7358, -84.4844),
 (42.3831, -83.1022),
 (42.2747, -85.5883),
 (42.2753, -83.7308),
 (42.7092, -84.5539),
 (42.9614, -85.6558),
 (46.4844, -84.3656)]


cities2 = [(x[1], x[0]) for x in cities]
print(cities)
#Output:
[(-84.4844, 42.7358),
 (-83.1022, 42.3831),
 (-85.5883, 42.2747),
 (-83.7308, 42.2753),
 (-84.5539, 42.7092),
 (-85.6558, 42.9614),
 (-84.3656, 46.4844)]
```

As for reversing a list, there are [many ways to reverse a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python). some create a copy, others modify the original list, such as `.reverse()`

```
cities3 = cities[::-1] #created a reversed copy.
#Alternatively
cities3 = list(reversed(cities))
```

Lastly however, a recommendation.

Your lists of tuples as-is do not make a lot of sense, but the name labels give the tuples meaning.

You should consider a different data structure to store this information,and [dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python) in this case makes sense. You can think of them as mappings between `key:value` pairs.

```
EL = (42.7358, -84.4844)
Det = (42.3831, -83.1022)
Kal = (42.2747, -85.5883)
AA = (42.2753, -83.7308)
Lan = (42.7092, -84.5539)
GR = (42.9614, -85.6558)
SSM = (46.4844, -84.3656)

cities = [EL, Det, Kal, AA, Lan, GR, SSM]
city_names = ["EL", "Det", "Kal", "AA", "Lan", "GR", "SSM"]
cities_dict = dict(zip(city_names, cities))
```

Note that the above code is equivalent the following:

```
cities_dict = {"EL": EL,
          "Det": Det,
          "Kal": Kal,
          "AA": AA,
          "Lan": Lan,
          "GR": GR,
          "SSM": SSM
        }

print(cities_dict)
#Output:
{'EL': (42.7358, -84.4844),
 'Det': (42.3831, -83.1022),
 'Kal': (42.2747, -85.5883),
 'AA': (42.2753, -83.7308),
 'Lan': (42.7092, -84.5539),
 'GR': (42.9614, -85.6558),
 'SSM': (46.4844, -84.3656)}
```

Now, a caveat, dictionaries are unordered inherently. If you want a dict-like data structure that supports ordering, use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
from collections import OrderedDict
cities = [EL, Det, Kal, AA, Lan, GR, SSM]
city_names = ["EL", "Det", "Kal", "AA", "Lan", "GR", "SSM"]
cities_dict = OrderedDict(zip(city_names, cities))
print(cities_dict)

cities2_dict = OrderedDict((key, (v[1], v[0])) for (key,v) in cities_dict.items())
print(cities2_dict)

cities3_dict = OrderedDict(reversed(cities_dict.items()))
print(cities3_dict)
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for giving me some ideas. It very helpful. Did not expect to use Dictionary earlier. Many thanks!