# Variable p referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to solve a problem I already solved before but now using list comprehensions. The problem is simple I have a list and I want to invert it using list comprehension

Defining the first list was easy but when I append the inverted list it gives me the error in the title. I know we should not append in list comprehensions but I don't know what to put.

```
v=[]
p=[]

def listt():
    v=[int(input('Digit element\n'))for j in range(0,int(input('Digit number of elements')))]
    return v
print(listt())

def invert_list(v):
    p=[p.append(v[j]) for j in range(len(v),-1,-1)]
    return p
print(invert_list(v))
```

Comment: In practice you won't use a list comp when you can just write `v[::-1]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3940128/953482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a local variable; you can't append to it before it exists.

It's not clear why you want the global variables `p` and `v` (note that `listt` does not modify the global `v`).

```
def listt():
     return [int(input('Digit element\n'))for j in range(0,int(input('Digit number of elements')))]

def invert_list(v):
    return [v[j] for j in range(len(v)-1,-1,-1)]

x = listt()
print(x)
print(invert_list(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead of `p=[p.append(v[j]) for j in range(len(v),-1,-1)]`:

```
p=[v[j] for j in range(len(v),-1,-1)]
```

Comment: the thing i dont understand is in what point you are telling you want to append? you simply wrote v[j] for j in range(len(V),-1,-1). That will invert the list but imagine i want to append some other values where does the append enter in list comprehension?

Comment: There is no appending in list comprehension. list comprehension creates a new list with items that are iterating inside.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing -

```
p=[p.append(v[j]) for j in range(len(v),-1,-1)]
```

`p` does not exist, hence the error.

You can do the following -

```
def invert_list(v):
    p = []
    for j in range(len(v)-1,-1,-1):
         p.append(v[j])
    return p
```

Comment: but can i do it using list comprehension?

Comment: yes i cant do it . I think i cant append when using list compreghensions