# How to sort list from latest user input to last

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-input

Hey guys I want the list that the user is creating with input to print in the order from latest entry to first entry..

the code I have right now does it for a few posts then it prints the list in some weird order

```
all_status_updates = []


def status():
    while True: 
        status = input("Type Status Update Here...\n")
        if status != "exit":
            all_status_updates.append(status)
            all_status_updates.sort(reverse = True) 
            print(all_status_updates)
        elif status == "exit":
            break
status()
```

Comment: Can you please show us the output? Are you confused by sorting strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Several things, which might not work in your example:

- You do not need to `sort()`, but to reverse the order of your list. For this you can use list slicing
- You should not name the variable for user input `status`, which is the same name as the function

```
def status():

    all_status_updates = []
    while True: 
        stat = input("Type Status Update Here...\n")
        if stat != "exit":
            all_status_updates.append(stat)
            print(all_status_updates[::-1])
        elif stat == "exit":
            break

status()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Type Status Update Here...
a
['a']
Type Status Update Here...
b
['b', 'a']
Type Status Update Here...
c
['c', 'b', 'a']
Type Status Update Here...
d
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
Type Status Update Here...
e
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
Type Status Update Here...
f
['f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
Type Status Update Here...
exit
```

Comment: This does not change anything?

Comment: thank you so much Simon! and will do thanks again for all the help

Comment: Did you read the question ? "I want the list that the user is creating with input to print in the order from latest entry to first entry".

Comment: @hauntboy this does not answer your question. And it will actually make no difference (except for saving a couple cpu cycles).

Comment: I'm very sorry, I was so convinced my solution would work, that I didn't test it. Now I did and now it should show the right behaviour.

Comment: thanks but Simon I want the list to print after every entry not just at the end yours works but without printing after every entry which is not what I'm going for

Comment: In this case, you cannot use `reverse()`, as it reverts the list inplace. You need to use list slicing in this case. I'll edit.

Comment: that did it weird I tried the slicing and it did not work for me earlier because I was adding the slicing in the wrong place thanks Simon! appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

When you **sort**, it will put the inputs in **alphabetical order**.
If you just want to **reverse** the list, use `myList.reverse()`
EDIT : reverse only at the end to have the expected result.

```
all_status_updates = []


def status():
    while True: 
        status = input("Type Status Update Here...\n")
        if status != "exit":
            all_status_updates.append(status)
            print(all_status_updates)
        elif status == "exit":
            break
    all_status_updates.reverse()
    print(all_status_updates)

status()
```

Comment: this does not do it instead it does the latest entry and right next to it is the first entry and so on I tried this before posting here

Comment: Reversing the list within each iteration will not show the desired result.

Comment: You are both right, I edited my answer with the reverse only once at the end