# Python remove list with duplicated fields in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to be able to remove an element from a list of list when a field in a list is duplicated in python3.

I.E:

Remove from the following list of lists when the second field is duplicated. From

`[["John","France"], ["Mike", "France"], ["Ana","Italy"]]`

To

`[["John","France"], ["Ana","Italy"]]`

Edit:
I have tried the following loop, but I am looking forward to a more efficient way if it exists.

```
for element in consult_array:
    for other_elements in consult_array:
        if element[1] == other_elements[1]:
            if element != other_elements:
                consult_array.pop(element)
```

Comment: Did you try using one or more `for` loops and `if` statements?

Comment: add each country to a dict everytime a new one found and then, if a country is on the dict pop it out of the list?

Comment: Yes @mkrieger1, I will edit my answer with the code. I was looking for a more efficient way (if it exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
data = [["John", "France"], ["Mike", "France"], ["Ana", "Italy"]]

output = []
already_seen_countries = set()

for item in data:
    country = item[1]
    if country not in already_seen_countries:
        output.append(item)
        already_seen_countries.add(country)

print(output)  # [['John', 'France'], ['Ana', 'Italy']]
```

Comment: If anyone is facing this problem in the future: To remove it from the original list, I put this code in a function with the list as arg, and I am returning the output and assinging it to the original list.

Answer (score 0):

if you like one line solutions:

```
l = [["John","France"], ["Mike", "France"], ["Ana","Italy"]]
list(t for t in {e[1]: e for e in l[::-1]}.values())[::-1]
```

output:

```
[['John', 'France'], ['Ana', 'Italy']]
```

Comment: Can you explain the significance of `[::-1]`?

Comment: this does not "remove" the items, it creates a new list

Comment: @mkrieger1 to [reverse a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Comment: I know, but why is it necessary here?

Comment: @PabloTatoRamos the end result is the same, where is the problem?