# Python parent objects within 1 list

Tags: python, list, parent, maya, pymel

I have a bit of an issue with parenting joints which are in one list.

```
spineJn = ['spine_IK_Jnt_A', 'spine_IK_Jnt_B', 'spine_IK_Jnt_C', 'spine_IK_Jnt_D', 'spine_IK_Jnt_E', 'spine_IK_Jnt_F', 'spine_IK_Jnt_G']
```

So, i need to make a joint chain out of these joints in this list. Key point is that I want to make it in reverse, meaning that the top Parent Joint is 'spine_IK_Jnt_A' and the end of the chain to be with 'spine_IK_Jnt_G'

I'm sorry for asking simple question, but I couldn't find anything online.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Reverse a list: `spineJn[::-1]` or `list(reversed(spineJn))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Comment: What is your expected output : a list of strings or a concatenated string ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to refer to multiple items in a list at once, I believe it's the most straightforward to use indexes to manipulate your position within the list.

```
for index in range(len(spineJn) - 1):  # Iterate from 0 to 5 so we don't get an IndexError by going over 6 by doing + 1
    pm.parent(spineJn[index + 1], spineJn[index])
```

Alternatively, with some zip magic:

```
for cur, nxt in zip(spineJn, spineJn[1:]):  # spineJn[1:] offsets the list by one, and then we combine the two lists with zip
    pm.parent(nxt, cur)
```

Hope this helps!