# Printing a list in reverse order

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I have to get this output:
[2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4]**

i tried this approach but our teacher wants the answer in ***one liner.***

```
x=list(range(-4,3))
y=x[::-1]
y
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Comment: list(range(2, -5, -1)) would also be an option

Comment: It looks like you already know how to reverse a list. You can easily take what you know and do it in one line: `print(list(range(-4,3))[::-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine all your lines in one:

```
print(list(range(-4,3))[::-1])
```

**output**

```
[2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4]
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do this:

```
print(list(range(-4,3))[::-1])
print(list(range(2,-3,-1)))
```

It's really good though that you're trying things and have the humility to ask for help when you're stuck. Teacher will be proud of you.