# How to return a reversed list back to its original state in python

Tags: python

I was just curious as to whether or not there is a function to turn a reversed list back to its original form or would the solution just to be to write the code to return it myself?

I do understand that i can simply assign the list to a variable(x) prior to reversing and then just assign the list back to x, but i am just curious.

I did think that calling the reverse() function twice would do this, but it did not,

Any answers are appreciated.

```
my_list = ["This", "is", "an", "example", "list"]
x = my_list
my_list.reverse()
print(my_list)
my_list = x
print(my_list)
```

Comment: "reverse" should do. Show your code properly formatted in the question.

Comment: Can you provide your example?

Comment: reversing the list again should do the trick. try list_name[::-1]. If it doesn't work can you please share your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) instead (which would return a new reversed iterable instead of reversing the list in place)

```
my_list = ["This", "is", "an", "example", "list"]
x = list(reversed(my_list))
print(x)
print(my_list)
```

**output:**

```
['list', 'example', 'an', 'is', 'This']
['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'list']
```