# How to change a [1,2,3...20] list onto [[1,2..20], [20,19....1]] nested list?

Tags: python

[PYTHON] Hello i have to create a list which starts at 1 and ends at 20, and then convert this list into a nested list which should look like this: `[[1,2,...,20],[20,19,...1]]`.

I did only this:

```
list = []
for i in range(1,21):
    lista.append(i)
    i += 1
```

which gives me a normal `[1, ... 20]` list,
but I don't know how to change it to a nested list with a reverse list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to simply do this (don't use `list` as variable name):

```
myList = [[x for x in range(1,21)],[y for y in range(21,0,-1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a nested list to begin with:

```
l = [ [], [] ]
for i in range(20):
    l[0].append(i+1)       # fills the first inner list with 1...20
    l[-1].append(20-i)     # fills the last inner list with 20...1

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 
 [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reverse a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python) using slicing and [concat both list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python).

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
ans = [arr] + [arr[::-1]]
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Easify `arr` assignment with `arr = list(range(1,21))`

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_list = [list(range(1, 21)), list(range(21, 0 ,-1))]
```

Comment: Cheeky answer that I like. But it ignores the "and then convert this list into a nested list " part.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question 
improves its long-term value. Consider reading [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit] your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
>>> x = [i for i in range(1, 21)]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
>>> r = [x, x[::-1]]
>>> r
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```