# how to print out a range with the single digit right justified

Tags: python

For example, if I had a range of 10, it would print:

9
8
7

and so on. Then when I have double digits, so with a range of 11, it prints out:

10
9
8

But, I want it to print out with the 9 under the 0 instead. Any way to do this?

Comment: `for i in range(10,7,-1): print(f"{i:2}")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reverse a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @Countour-Integral that is totally different than this question. This question is about right-justification, not list reversal.

Comment: My bad, i am braindead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [str.**rjust**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rjust#str.rjust):

```
for i in reversed(range(1, 11)):
    print(str(i).rjust(2))
```

**Output:**

```
10
 9
 8
 7
 6
 5
 4
 3
 2
 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
for i in range(11)[::-1]:
    print(f"{i:>2}")
```

If you want three-digit numbers, change the 2 to a 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a space at the beginning of the number.
I just calculate the amount of digits and pad the lower number with spaces

```py
max = 1337
max_len = len(str(max))
for i in reversed(range(max)):
    str_len = len(str(i))
    if max_len > str_len:
        difference = max_len - str_len #calculate amount of needed spaces
        print(" " * difference + str(i)) #pad string with spaces
    else:
        print(i)
```