# Guys I want to know why the code below could not modify the list in reverse order. I am getting [8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8] when I run the code. P assist

Tags: python

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for num in range(len(x)):  
    x[num] = x[-(num + 1)]
print(x)
```

Guys I want to know why the code above could not modify the list in reverse order. I am getting `[8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8]` when I run the code . Please kindly assist

Comment: You're overwriting the list as you're iterating over it. Print `x` in each iteration and you'll see.

Comment: Please read [ask]. The title to your question is just awful.

Comment: As a new user here, please also take the [tour].

Comment: why don't you just give `x = x[::-1]` and see what you get? I have also posted the link to the duplicate question. See the link for more details

Comment: because you reverse it twice

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the string, all you need to do is `mylist.reverse()` or `mylist[::-1]`. For more details on this, please see [Stack Overflow response from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807295/13873980).

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

x = x[::-1]
```

Original list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Updated list:

```
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing existing values, and then looping back over them.
What you want to use is the reverse method.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
x.reverse()
print(x)
```

Comment: They want to reverse it, not sort.

Comment: @bereal ah I think you are correct. I couldn't tell after they used "for num in range(len(x))". Thanks