# How to give the opposite of each numeral element of a list using Python

Tags: python, list, digital-signature

Is there any way in Python to give the opposite of each numeral element of a list in one line, without doing, for example:

```py
list_ = list(range(10))
for x in range(len(list_)):
    list_[x] = -list_[x]
```

In this case, considering the list

> `[0,  1,  2,  3...,  9]`

the output should be

> `[0, -1, -2, -3..., -9]`

Every number of the list should be its opposite.

---

I tried `-list_` but it didn't work.

I searched but I found only how to [*reverse*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python) a list, and not how to *oppose* its elements (I hope this is the correct word, meaning that each number should end up being its additive inverse.)

---

I know about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but I was wondering if there was a special keyword in Python to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input values are numeric, you can do something like this

```py
negated_values=map(lambda x:-x, mylist)
```

where

```py
print(list(negated_values))
```

returns

```
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use numpy arrays which have the properties you want:

```
import numpy as np

list_ = np.array(range(10))
list_inv = - list_
```

Which gives

```
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list_ = range(10)
list_ = [-x for x in list_]
```

or

```
list_ = range(10)
list_ = list(map(lambda x: -x, list_))
```

or

```
list_ = range(0,-10,-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invert a list without using either a list comprehension or map as others have suggested (i.e. the simplest possible single command) you could do it with Numpy, but you'd have to convert to a Numpy array first (which obviously adds its own complexity). Then you can just negate the array e.g.

```
import numpy as np

x = [1, -2, 3]
arr = np.array(x)

arr    
Output: array([ 1, -2,  3])

-arr
Output: array([-1,  2, -3])
```