# How to create a function within a stack class that can display a stack in a last in first out way in Python?

Tags: python, class, stack

I have created a stack class with functions such as pop, push, peek etc.

How do I create another function within the class to print a stack in last in first out way?

My class:

```
class Thestack:

  def __init__(self):
    self.elements = []

  def push(self, data):
    self.elements.append(data)

  def pop(self):
    if self.elements:
        return self.elements.pop()
    else:
        return None

  def top(self):
    return self.elements[-1]

  def size(self):
    return len(self.elements)
```

I have tried that with s.pop():

```
def display(self):
      while len(self.elements) > 0:
        print(self.pop())
```

But then the stack is empty.

is that anyway to retain/restore the order/ the original stack after displaying the stack?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Thestack.push(7)
Thestack.push(8)
Thestack.push(9)
Thestack.Display()
print("Size = " + str(Thestack.size()))

Output:
9
8
7
Size = 3
```

Comment: It would be advised to show your complete class alongwith the members declared

Comment: @RupalShah Thanks for the reminder, I have added it to the question.

Comment: def display(self):   
     for i in range(self.size()-1,-1,-1):  
        print(self.elements[i])

Comment: Can you clarify your constraints? You can directly ``print(self.elements)``. Are you restricted to constraint operations?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried it before, but it only displays in the first in first out way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-to-reverse-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is:

```py
for element in reversed(self.elements):
    print(element)
```

See https://linuxize.com/post/python-list-reverse/ for explanation about reversing lists.

Answer (score -1):

We can have a function that prints the elements in reverse order. So we start our loop from size-1 and would print upto index zero by decrementing the index by 1. So that makes our function as:

```
def display(self): 
    for i in range(self.size()-1,-1,-1): 
        print(self.elements[i])
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.