# Takes array as parameter and returns a reverse array using loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, reverse

```
# Function that takes array as parameter and returns a reverse array 
# using loop

def reverse_list(arr = []):
    for i in arr[::-1]:
        print(i)
arr_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(reverse_list(arr_num))
```

I want my function to take an array as a parameter, but I'm not sure if the structure /code of it is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-to-reverse-a-list

Comment: @BenjaminW., I already get the output that I want. But I want to verify if my code is correct when taking an array as a parameter.

Comment: Your function does not return a list, it only prints the result in reverse

Comment: If you want to print the list reversely - you just did.  But if you want a *reversed List* - your code did not work.

Comment: Okay, now I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a new array inside the function and either append each values before returning it

```py
def reverse_list(arr = []):
    new_arr = []
    for i in arr[::-1]:
        # print(i)
        new_arr.append(i)
    return new_arr


arr_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(reverse_list(arr_num))
```

Or in short assign the reversed array to the new array

```py
def reverse_list(arr = []):
    new_arr = arr[::-1]
    return new_arr
```

Comment: In the 2nd one - don't need  *new_arr* var. just return the *arr[::-1]* would be better.

Comment: You're right, it's just a stylistic habit when the value(s) is too long, just for readability

Answer (score 1):

Your function will not work since it's not *returning* the list.

Here is one way to solve this problem - using the for-loop:

```
def reverse_list(arr):
    result = []
    
    for i, _ in enumerate(arr):    # try to use enumerate - it's better in most cases
        result.append(arr[~i])     # use the backward indexing here
        
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) builtin function;

```
>>> reversed([1,2,3,4])
[4,3,2,1]
```

but if you wanted to have a function to return it, i will advise to use the `slice` indexing:

```
def rev_list(lst):
    return lst[::-1]
```

**Edit**: Use backward indexing,

```
def rev(lst):
    for i,x in enumerate(list(lst)):
        lst[~i] = x
    return lst
```

You can do it also by list comprehension:

```
def reverse(lst):
    return [tmp[i] for i in range(0,len(lst)-1,-1)]
```

Comment: I think OP knows that, he's practicing the *for-loop* to learn the language.

Comment: I know I can use it. But I want to achieve it using _for loop_

Answer (score 1):

With a list comprehension together with the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) build-in function (it returns a *generator*):

```
def reverse_list(lst):
    return [v for v in reversed(lst)]
    # or return list(reversed(lst))
```

Another version but without *for*-loop to highlight the underlying processes:

Using build-in function [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) to select a range of items in a sequence object
and select an element from the container with `__getitem__` subscription.

```
def reverse_list(lst):
    # slice object
    s = slice(None, None, -1)
    # selection
    return lst.__getitem__(s) # <--> lst[s]
```