# change the order of numbers from the back

Tags: python

they need to order with a problem

so I have the text in a certain order of numbers, something like gematria

`input [12345]` is what we call gematria and what do they need?

they need to line up the digits backwards

`[54321]`
have a different count and I would need help with that rather than doing twenty different if

```
def shiftall(s, n):
     n %= len(s)
     return s[n:] + s[:n]
```

it didn't help me much it only moves the simple text

Comment: what is s? a string? a list? a number?

Comment: What is your question? You just want to reverse the order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-to-reverse-a-list)

Comment: The function you showed is for rotating a list, not reversing it.

Comment: @Ryan number/strig

Comment: @CrazyChucky  yes, I want to reverse the order exactly

Comment: @NelsonGon sory im new

Comment: You can read the answers on the duplicate post and if they work mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strings:

```
return s[::-1]
```

For integers:

```
return str(s)[::-1]
```

Note: This would go inside `def shiftall(s, n):`
Additional note: Now you don't even need the parameter `n`

Comment: `test = "1234"

print(test[::-1])`  yes thanx :D  it didn't occur to me that it could also work with whole numbers, I learned something new again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse a number, then you can convert it to a string, reverse the string, and then convert it back to a number.

```py
num = 12345
str_num = str(num)
# reverse and convert
num = int(str_num[::-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

input=[12345,43545436,88888,843546]

```
def shiftall(s):            
d=[]
for i in s:

    res=''.join(reversed(str(i)))

    d.append(int(res))

return d
```

print(shiftall(input))