# Group reversed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv("some_data.csv")

candles = [Candle(candle["close"].iloc[0], candle["close"].iloc[-1], max(candle["close"]), min(candle["close"]))
           for _, candle in df.groupby(df.index // ticks)]
candles.reverse()
```

With a dataframe full of tick data. It works but feels a bit clumsy - so my question: isn't it possible to group the reversed dataframe in the first place?

---

This is a snippet of the actual data:

```
timestamp,close,security_code,volume,bid_volume,ask_volume
2024-02-28 01:00:00.358537+00:00,18002.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:00.890809+00:00,18002.75,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:00.890809+00:00,18002.75,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:01.696411+00:00,18002.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:02.268716+00:00,18002.25,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:02.513397+00:00,18002.5,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:03.716795+00:00,18002.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:03.892441+00:00,18002.75,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:03.893664+00:00,18002.25,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:06.956017+00:00,18002.25,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:08.144158+00:00,18002.25,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:08.144158+00:00,18002.25,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:08.772717+00:00,18002.0,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:08.772717+00:00,18002.0,NQ,3,0,3
2024-02-28 01:00:09.966515+00:00,18002.25,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:10.051715+00:00,18002.0,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:11.053980+00:00,18001.75,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:11.053980+00:00,18001.75,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:11.296008+00:00,18002.0,NQ,1,1,0
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.75,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.25,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.25,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.25,NQ,1,0,1
2024-02-28 01:00:12.050765+00:00,18001.25,NQ,2,0,2
```

Comment: candles.iloc[::-1] should reverse your dataframe. Then you can just group it right?

Comment: @MitchellLeefers: But I'd love to reverse the df first.

Comment: @Jan Can't you add `[::-1]` at the end? Something like `candles = [...][::-1]`. That way you can omit the `candles.reverse()` line.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: But isn't that as insufficient as the `.reverse()` call? My idea was to reverse the df in the first place and then group it.

Comment: @Jan Well, something has to be reversed at the end. I think reversing the list holding `Candle()` objects would be more efficient than reversing the whole dataframe.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: But is `[::-1]` faster then `.reverse()` ?

Comment: `.reverse()` is several times faster than `[::-1]` although only significant on very large Lists

Comment: @Jan According my testing, `list.reverse()` should be faster. Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807295/10035985

Comment: @AndrejKesely: Well, then, the code is the most efficient already, isn't it?

Comment: @Jan I think yes. Perhaps this `.groupby()` could be rewritten with `numba`, but that's other question.

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE?  Sample dataframe input and expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston: I added some sample data. I just want to know which one is faster as the data is about 60-80 MB / day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively it seems that doing the aggregation inside the groupby would be more efficient. As a small example:

```py
class Candle:
    def __init__(self, open, close, high, low):
        self.open = open
        self.close = close
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
        
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'close' : random.choices(range(50, 70),k=50) })

df['close'].values
#
# array([66, 67, 57, 65, 64, 63, 59, 54, 57, 50, 58, 67, 69, 53, 54, 53, 54,
#        62, 53, 67, 69, 51, 65, 64, 56, 63, 58, 54, 50, 51, 63, 69, 55, 66,
#        54, 54, 64, 52, 52, 58, 57, 61, 64, 63, 53, 64, 50, 52, 68, 63],
#       dtype=int64)

candles = (df[::-1]
    .groupby(df.index[::-1]//ticks, sort=False)['close']
    .agg(open='last', close='first', high='max', low='min')
    .apply(lambda g:Candle(*g), axis=1)
    .tolist()
)

for c in candles:
    print(c.__dict__)
```

Sample output:

```
{'open': 64, 'close': 63, 'high': 68, 'low': 50}
{'open': 57, 'close': 53, 'high': 64, 'low': 53}
{'open': 54, 'close': 58, 'high': 64, 'low': 52}
{'open': 63, 'close': 54, 'high': 69, 'low': 54}
{'open': 63, 'close': 51, 'high': 63, 'low': 50}
{'open': 69, 'close': 56, 'high': 69, 'low': 51}
{'open': 53, 'close': 67, 'high': 67, 'low': 53}
{'open': 58, 'close': 54, 'high': 69, 'low': 53}
{'open': 63, 'close': 50, 'high': 63, 'low': 50}
{'open': 66, 'close': 64, 'high': 67, 'low': 57}
```